# Regression Predictions

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I don't think I fully explained my last question because it was marked as a duplicate. I went to the other question, and read it through several times, and it was asking something very different.

Trying again:

I have two variables that both influence Y, and I calculated regression equations for each. Based on the slope coefficients, am I able to determine if one is a better predictor of Y than the other, or do I have to find the correlation now to do that?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of using both variables simultaneously to predict $Y$?  Incidentally, the (raw) slope coefficients tell you nothing about predictability: after all, if you merely change the units of measurement of one of the independent variables, the corresponding slope will also change: but a change of units of measure obviously will not change your ability to predict the dependent variable!